# Updating UIView's background color in a while loop

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3

I would like to change the color of a `UIView` in a while loop. I am calling `start()` from the main thread.

Example :

```
func start() {

    let item = Percolation(n: self.tileSideCount)

    while (!item.percolates()) {
        let v = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.tileSideCount))) + 1
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.tileSideCount))) + 1

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
            self.container?.viewWithTag(v)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.container?.viewWithTag(j)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in

        })

        if (!item.isOpen(i: v, j: j)) {
            item.open(i: v, j: j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.container?.viewWithTag(v/j)` could be nil

Comment: Which part does not work?

Comment: So you're randomly changing view background colors to white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the colors to change from one to the next in sequence, you need to submit your animation calls with delay and duration values so the previous animation is finished as the next one starts.

Say the duration of each animation is 1 second. Make the first one start with a delay of 0, the second animation start with a delay of 1 second, etc.

(Same applies for other durations. if your duration is .3 second, have each subsequent animation start an additional 0.3 seconds later than the previous one.)